# Open Lightning Web Component which belongs to unlocked package

Tags: lightning-web-components, unlocked-package

How to open and edit lwc which belongs to unlocked package? In VScode it doesn't displayed and when I go to package in salesforce site code of component is not displayed as well. So VScode doesn't display source from unlocked packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the contents of the unlocked package from the command line using below command

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "<package name>"
```

This will give a separate folder which you can take the contents and move to your working folder.

The VSCODE Extension pack for Salesforce has made some [fixes](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/pull/2305) but they are not yet out and may be in a week or so this is out. Till then you can use command line.